# Can't stop EC2 instance, because of system health-check

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a ELB EC2 instance, I want to pause it by stopping it, so I can attach a new volume to it, but it will terminate the instance instead.

Because: instance was taken out of service in response to a system health-check.
Any work rounds for this?

Comment: Why can't you post it there?

Comment: Turns out I can't

Comment: Anyone with access to have an EC2 instance should have access to post there. Chances are AWS support is going to ask for an instance ID etc. that someone else couldn't provide.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that unless your instance is not in an auto scaling group you can stop / start it whenever you please and it will not be replaced. If you're instance is in an auto scaling group you can temporarily pause the auto scaling group buy running the command.

`as-suspend-processes AutoScalingGroupName`

Then after you're done updating the server and it is back online

`as-resume-processes AutoScalingGroupName`

Comment: I already tried to remove the instance from the Elastic Load Balancer, but that didn't work. Could it have something to do with the fact that I am using Ylastic with a "MyLowCPUAlarm" set to manage my instances?

Comment: Btw. Could you be so nice to ask this question on the official Amazon AWS forums for me, just to be 100% sure?

Comment: The ELB will not shut down an instance. It will just stop sending requests to the instance. If you have it in an auto scaling group and the health check for the auto scaling group is configured as ELB and not EC2 then when the healthcheck for the ELB fails it will replace the instance. But it will only do that if you're using auto scaling groups. However if all you're trying to do is attach a new volume, you can do that without stopping the instance without any problems.

Comment: No, you can't attach a new volume in Windows Server 2008, in Windows Server 2003, this would be no problem.

Comment: I do it all the time with my windows server 2008 please explain why this wont work.